# WPF: How to save only one Settings variable?

Tags: c#, wpf, settings

Is there any way to save only one variable as default in my Settings? I know there is a command `Properties.Settings.Default.Save();`, but I want to save the change of just one of my Settings variables, not all of them.

Comment: just update only one setting token before calling Properties.Settings.Default.Save().

Comment: Ok, but when I change more than one of the Settings variables and than I want to save just one of them, is there any way to approach this? I could maybe store the value of this variable to temporary variable than reload the settings and than save just the change of this one...

Comment: Well, why do you want to change the setting value if you don't want to save it ?

Comment: I may using the Setting wrong way, but I have bool witch indicates, whether one of the menus should be visible. And I want to let user choose if he want to store this setting. But I have also some other setting, which I want to save every time they are changed...

Comment: Isn't it better to use an auxiliary variable to save your final settings ? You could store your menu visibility data in some other variables or class, and on every change keep saving your other settings, and in the end, save menu visibility settings.

Comment: Yes, that's definitely better approach, I will do it that way, thanks. If you answer I will mark your answer as best...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to save an individual property value in the Designer-generated `Settings` object. You can save only the whole object or none at all.

Note that the settings are saved in an XML file, which would make writing out just a single value impractical anyway. Note also that writing this XML file is relatively cheap; it's typically a tiny file (unless you are serializing some huge piece of data in your `Settings` object), and can be written over and over will little impact on performance in your program (especially if you're only writing it in response to user actions…users are extremely slow, as compared to the computer).

You should, in general, *not* defer writing the `Settings` object until the program exits. It's quite appropriate to call `Settings.Default.Save()` any time any setting (or group of settings) is modified, to ensure that the settings are actually persisted to the disk regardless of what happens later in the program (e.g. it crashes).

Finally note that in terms of your specific scenario – one flag that indicates whether or not to show a menu, and another flag that indicates whether to persist this value or not – you don't necessarily need to add yet another flag elsewhere and conditionally save based on the first flag.

Instead, just keep the two flags in your `Settings` object, e.g. `Settings.Default.RememberMenuVisibleSettings` and `Settings.Default.MenuVisible`. Then as the first thing when your program starts, you can check `RememberMenuVisibleSettings` and if it's set to `false`, just initialize `MenuVisible` to its default setting, overriding whatever was saved to the settings file. Then the rest of your program doesn't need to worry about it; no special handling of either flag needs to occur after that point. You can just save both normally, with the confidence that when the program starts again it will do the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

Your question hints at a design issue:

Users expect a clear abstraction with settings:

- Load all settings at program start
- Probably modify settings during program execution
- save all settings before program exits

If you need somethin like "edit some values but do not save as settings" then you should introduce an additional layer which does exactly that: allows changing some values without modifying the settings.